# I need to alter a column on table if certain conditions apply

Tags: mysql

I have a brands table with following fields. [image]

And I need to add the "id" from brands table to "brand_id" column on "products table" if "platform" field matches "name" field from brands table, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE products p,
brands b
SET products.brand_id = brand.id where products.platform = brands.name
```

Comment: We can also use join as well in query.

Comment: This answer worked but I had to remove p,b from query.